# multiple=multiple in cakephp creates additional hidden field

Tags: cakephp, html-select

I have a `select-option` field in my form as below:

```
<div>
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('employee_id', array('label' => 'Hi','multiple'=>true,'id'=>'multiselect', 'options' => $employee));?>
</div>
```

But when I checked the page-source, it produces an additional `hidden` field in my form.

```
<div>
<div class="input select">
<label for="multiselect">Hi</label>
<input type="hidden" name="data[Participant][employee_id]" value="" id="multiselect_"/>
<select name="data[Participant][employee_id][]" multiple="multiple" id="multiselect">
<option value="1">A1</option>
<option value="2">A2</option>
<option value="3">A3</option>
<option value="4">A4</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
```

Whats the reason ? I am not able to get the employee id array due to this in my POST data.

Answer (score 0):

That's so that if no items are selected, you still get an empty element being POSTed.

It's a similar idea as the blank item above a checkbox -- if the checkbox is not selected then the form data is still posted, just with a blank value.